# How to copy files without erasing files with are not concerned by the copy in destination folder

Tags: ssh, copy

Is it possible to copy only a group of files without erasing some files in destination folder.

I have a folder « One » with contain :

```
 file-b.php
 file-d.php
```

In folder « two », I have

```
 file-a.php
 file-b.php
 file-c.php
 file-d.php
```

I want to copy files from  `folder « One »` to `folder « two »` I just want to replace `file-b.php` end  `file-d.php` without erasing `file-a.php` and `file-d.php`

A the end, `folder « two »`, should be like this :

```
 file-a.php
 file-b.php (modified)
 file-c.php
 file-d.php (modified)
```

I've tried various things with `mv` and `cp` without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I should delete my question since I found a solution. In case it could help, here is my solution :

```
cp -Rf /path/to/folder-1/* /path/to/folder-2
```

`-R` instructs `cp` to copy files recursively (for example, a whole directory). To overwrite already existing files you should use the `-f` argument: